# C#: How to remove item from dictionary using reflection?

Tags: reflection, dictionary

I have a dictionary where keys can be string or decimal. The values can be different type of objects. I want to write the code that can manage removing dictionary items in all cases.

The code I'd like to replace is as follows:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, Parus.Metadata.Units.Unit> objDict = cacheItem.Value as ConcurrentDictionary<string, Parus.Metadata.Units.Unit>;
foreach (var detaildGrid in this.MasterGridFrameControl.ChildFrames)
{
    foreach (GridDataItem item in detaildGrid.GridControl.SelectedItems)
    {
        object dataKey = item.GetDataKeyValue("SubKey");
        objDict.Remove((string)dataKey);
    }
}
```

Or as follows:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<decimal, Domain> objDict = cacheItem.Value as ConcurrentDictionary<decimal, Domain>;
foreach (GridFrameControl detaildGrid in this.MasterGridFrameControl.ChildFrames)
{
    foreach (GridDataItem item in detaildGrid.GridControl.SelectedItems)
    {
        object dataKey = item.GetDataKeyValue("SubKey");
        objDict.Remove((decimal)dataKey);
    }
}
```

The code should look as follows:

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in detaildGrid.GridControl.SelectedItems)
{
    object dataKey = item.GetDataKeyValue("SubKey");
    object[] parameters = { dataKey };
    Type t = cacheItem.Value.GetType();
    MethodInfo info = t.GetMethod("Remove");
    info.Invoke(cacheItem.Value, parameters);
}
```

But, I'm getting this error message: Ambiguous match found.

I've read some articles on internet where they said I should specify the second parameter in this call:

```
MethodInfo info = t.GetMethod("Remove");
```

But, I'm not sure how to do it.

Any help is appreciate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the type in `t`? Your code works fine for me.

Comment: t is dictionary where keys can be string or decimal and values can be different types.

Comment: Please show me the result of `t.ToString()`. If it would be a normal dictionary you shouldn't be getting this exception as dictionary only has one `Remove` method, so there is no ambiguity there...

Comment: Here it is: Parus.Common.Collections.ConcurrentDictionary`2[System.String,Parus.Metadata.CustomUnitClasses.CustomUnitClass]

Comment: It's not normal dictionary. It's custom dictionary with 2 Remove methods.

Comment: First Remove method is:         public bool Remove(TKey key)
        {
            using (new WriteLock(_lock))
            {
                return _dictionary.Remove(key);
            }
        }

Comment: And the second one is:         public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            using (new WriteLock(_lock))
            {
                return _dictionary.Remove(item);
            }
        }

Comment: I think I should use the first Remove method, but don't know how to do that using Invoke method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
var genericArguments = cacheItem.Value.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
var keyType = genericArguments[0]; // Maybe implement some error handling.
MethodInfo info = t.GetMethod("Remove", new [] { keyType });
```